# Excel.PivotField.DataRange.Cells.Group does not work. Why?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The following code won't build.

```
            var Date = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Date");
            Date.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
            Date.Position = 1;
            Date.DataRange.Cells[1].Group(true, true, Type.Missing, GroupParam);
```

`Group` is marked as causing an error. The error message is `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Group' and no extension method 'Group' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How can I fix this error?

I am using VS 2012 together with VSTO and add-in express

Comment: What is the type of `GroupParam`?  Does the situation improve if you declare an `Excel.Range` variable equal to `DataRange` or `Cells[1]`?  I am able to get worse code to compile and execute fine: `app.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("DATE").DataRange.Cells[1].Group(true, true, Type.Missing, new bool[] { false, false, false, false, true, true, false });`

Comment: Creating a range for Cells[1] solved the problem. Thank you for the solution! If you post it as a solution I'll be happy to accept it. Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)Date.DataRange.Cells[1];
                    rng.Group(true, true, Type.Missing, GroupParam);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably declare intermediate variables if you are experiencing compile issues.  It fairly apparent from testing that the `Group` method exists and should be accessible by your code.  Give the compiler some help and declare the variable:

The extreme version of this philosophy worked fine for me using `Group`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Excel.Worksheet sht = app.ActiveSheet;
    Excel.PivotTable pt = sht.PivotTables(1);
    Excel.PivotField pf = pt.PivotFields("DATE");

    Excel.Range rng = pf.DataRange;

    Excel.Range cell = rng.Cells[1];
    cell.Group(true, true, Type.Missing, new bool[] { false, false, false, false, true, true, false });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.Range rng = pf.DataRange;

    Excel.Range cell = rng.Cells[1];
    cell.Group(true, true, Type.Missing, new bool[] { false, false, false, true, false, true, true });
```

As mentioned above, There are number of parameter passed as true and false in bool array. The value is set to true or false depending on filter you want like for month, year etc.

See image. The parameter order is same as the passed value 
[image]